# Android: How to force an application to display itself as portrait no matter what device orientation

Tags: root-access, orientation

I have a rooted device, and the device orientation was in landscape mode but some of the application only designed for portrait screen. Is there a way to force the application to fit inside the landscape screen so the whole application can be visible within my rooted device.

Comment: Try **[Rotation Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.crape.rotationcontrol)** app..

Answer (score 0):

If you can install the [Xposed framework](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer), try the module [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings) which allows you to feed each app its own specific settings (including orientation).